# jQuery wait for Ajax if called

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, wait

I have the following code:

```
var table = new Array();
function getTableData(year) {
    if (!table.hasOwnProperty(year)) {
        $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function(data) {
                table[year] = data;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So, what I want that function to do is basically check, if I have called that Ajax-request before and if I have, don't call it again but return the previously loaded data.

This works like a charm. What does not work is this:

```
function showTable(year) {
    $('#loadingAnimation').show();
    $('#tableDiv').ajaxComplete(function() {
        // insert data into table
    }
    $('#loadingAnimation').hide();
}
```

As long as the data has not been loaded before (i.e. table[year] does not exist yet), the ajax-request is performed, when it's completed the data is inserted into the table and everything works great. But when table[year] does exist, my function doesn't have anything to wait for and I get a blank table plus the loading animation.

What I have tried before is to set the ajax-request to synchronous and don't let my function call "ajaxComplete", then everyting works but I get no loading animation at all, screen is just frozen during the waiting period.

Any ideas how I could make my script work?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `var table = Array();` needs to be `var table = [];` or `var table = new Array();`. However, I think in your case you want an object, i.e. `= {}` or `= new Object()`

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo in my post. Why would I need an object rather than an array? It's just a string?...

Comment: Unless `year` are values from 0..n an array is not really the best choice for it. some_array[2012] = ...; will create `0..2011` elements with the value `undefined`.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: What would you prefer to use instead?

Comment: An object, i.e. `var table = {};`. Then you can set any properties you want.

Comment: yup, thats right. crating `table` as an `array` and then setting `table[year]` with `year` = 2011 will actually create an array that long. try checking the `length` of this array, and it will say `2012`.  The concept of associative arrays resolves to nothing but objects in JavaScript. So the variable `year` is evaluated and then set as a property. => `table[year] = data` will evaluate `year` as a string say "2011" and set the property "2011" of `table` = `data`. Its same as `table = { "2011" : data }`

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason that `showTable()` is a seperate function? As in, a seperate button to refresh the table data after the initial load?

Otherwise you'll be better off adding the loading animation directly into your working code like this:

```
if (!table.hasOwnProperty(year)) {
    $('#loadingAnimation').show(); //start querying for data, display the icon
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(data) {
            $('#loadingAnimation').hide(); //data found, hide icon
            table[year] = data;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have arrow buttons on my page which, when clicked, call `showTable(year)` with the next (or previous) year as parameter. So I need to have a seperate function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by setting one more variable to store the previous table[year]. In all of your subsequent calls therefore, you would check it before doing anything else.
For eg. something like -

```
// An example from a dynamic AJAX gallery I had built        
var 
// ...,
prepareMarkup,
loadResults,
resultsCache = {},
// ...
;

loadResults = function(req, category, tracker) {
// I am calling loadResults on every click (navigation in ur case)
// to load galleries
// thus, tracker is different for each link

if (req && req !== "") {
    // I am using a tracker by setting to a link, 
    // which keeps track of those that users have already clicked 
    // at least once
    if (typeof resultsCache[tracker] === "object" 
        && resultsCache[tracker].lookbookResults.length > 0) {
        // Load from cache instead
        buildLookbook(resultsCache[tracker], category);
        return;
    }


    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/bin/content/lookbook",
        data: "lookbook-feed=" + req + "&siteName=" + APP.Site.siteRoot,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            // Set cache
            resultsCache[tracker] = response;

            // Go ahead to build UI
            buildLookbook(response, category);
        },

//...
```

Hope this is what you were looking for